# Code snippet runner for blog

Tags: wordpress, code-snippets

Is there a plugin that exist to create jsfiddle type of code runner (or  like Stackoverflow's code snippet runner) for the blog.

Blog is based on wordpress, and while creating blog, user can provide javascript, html, css like stackoverflow's code runner and when blog is rendered, user can just run/copy the code to see the result.

I could reuse jsfiddle (instead of reinventing the wheel), but then the snippet belongs to jsfiddle and then, it *may* be deleted at their own discretion.

Comment: Whatever you end up doing, make sure the snippets run in a sandbox. The domain used for the snippets on Stack Overflow explains why better then I ever can https://stacksnippets.net/

Comment: Thanks for that valuable tip @i-haz-kode That probably also suggest that embedding jsfiddle is an easier option than own snippets...